# How to change the colour of a dialog Activity's divider?

Tags: android

I have an activity that I display to the user as a dialog via a change in the manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dark.Dialog"
```

I haven't been able to find any help regarding how to change the divider via this method of calling a dialog - only from typical dialog code.

`setDivider` doesn't seem to be supported.

Thanks for any help.[image: Dialog Divider Pic]

Comment: That is actually not really achivelable using the standard framework, but what you can do is create a custom dialog with your own layout. This library could also be used if you don't want to write you own layout: https://github.com/inmite/android-styled-dialogs

Comment: That's what I've gathered from searching around about dialogs in general. Seems a bit strange for that one piece to be hardcoded in, doesn't it? Thanks for the link, I'm looking into it.

Comment: It does, and I've been really annoyed by it my self too.